# OSX - SysServices does not display custom menu in all apps (eg., chrome or safari)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, system-services

I've followed the sample plist provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-98488). I've also referred the info.plist from official Twitter app for mac.

For some reasons, even though my [Info.plist](https://github.com/palaniraja/services-menu/blob/master/menu/Info.plist#L31) properties for `NSServices` seems to be correct, my custom menu does not appear in all apps but available in few.

Eg., "My custom menu" is not listed in *Chrome* or *Safari*, but available in *TextEdit* if I right click and select "services" from context menu.

I have also tried moving the application from build directory to `/Applications` still no luck.

Sample project: https://github.com/palaniraja/services-menu

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with OSX.

Even after flush/updating the `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs` service. Rebooting the system did not help.

After couple of days, I got the services listed in Chrome & Safari. But under a old cached title of my service. Its been two weeks and I still live with dev copy of my title rather than the actual service name (title) in which currently this app is running.

[image: Screenshot of info.plist and safari]